# Best way to interleave two char arrays

Tags: pointers

I am looking for the best way to interleave two char arrays using a function that were input by the user. I am learning C++ and this is a homework so I can't use anything too advance assignment I am just curious if I am going the right direction with it.

I was thinking that using a for loop to iterate through each index in both arrays and then use the function to add the two chars and output them. I also have to use pointers for this assignment.

```
#include <iostream>;

using namespace std;

char* strinterleave(const char *a, const char *b) {
char done;
done = *a + *b;
}

int main() {

char interleave[]="";
char storage1[] = "";
char storage2[] = "";
int lena;
int lenb;


char *a_ptr = storage1;
char *b_ptr = storage2;



    cin.getline(storage1, numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ' ');
    cin.getline(storage2, numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
    lena = strlen(a_ptr);
    lenb = strlen(b_ptr);
    int finallen = lena + lenb;
    for (int j = 0; j <= finallen; ++j) {
        strinterleave(a_ptr[j], b_ptr[j]);

    }


}
```

Is this the wrong way to go about this and if so what would be the right direction to go?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things to consider:

The string lengths may not be the same.  You'll need to decide what do with any remaining characters in the longer string.

Examining your code...
 int finallen = lena + lenb;
 for (int j = 0; j <= finallen; ++j) { <--- Remember you are processing two characters at once, so you probably want something like the max of lena or lenb.
        strinterleave(a_ptr[j], b_ptr[j]); // <--- this is passing chars, not pointers to chars, so it doesn't match the function declaration.

char* strinterleave(const char *a, const char *b) { //<- Make this just chars, not char*)
char done;
done = *a + *b;  <-- Adding the characters won't interleave them.  I'm guessing your instructor wants a new string created with the characters interleaved.

For instance if you have:
storage1 = "123456"
storage2 = "abc"
The instructor probably wants:
finalString = "1a2b3c456"
}

Comment: Thank you Olan for the help. Going through two strings would it be optimal to run two for loops through both arrays?

Comment: Two loops would work.  One loop copies the first string.  While copying the chars from the first string you could leave spaces for the second string.  The tricky part is probably still dealing with different length strings.   I think your current single loop approach is fine too.

Comment: Again Thank you so much for your help and pointers, I don't have anyone to really bounce ideas off of. I guess I am just going to ask again if this is the right way to go right now? Right now my approach is to do a while loop that stops when the we reach the null terminator of the smallest array, then using a for loop I am going to somehow add the extra characters from the larger array to it.